# Is $\lim 2x \ge \lim \sqrt x $ at $a$ true for $a\in[1,\infty]$?

Tags: limits

> For $a \in [1,\infty)$, $$\lim_{x \to a}2x > \lim_{x \to a}\sqrt{x}$$ and when $a = \infty$, $$\lim_{x \to a} 2x = \lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{x}$$
> So, $\lim_{x \to a}2x \geq \lim_{x \to a}\sqrt{x}$ at $a$ for $a \in [1,\infty]$.

Is this right?
Can we put closed bracket at infinity?

Comment: Neither $2x$ nor $\sqrt x$ have limits as $x \to \infty$.  Otherwise, the limits at $a$ are $2a$ and $\sqrt{a}$, and $2a > \sqrt{a}$ when $a > \frac14$,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that for any $a\ge 1$ from $2x> \sqrt x$ we can only conclude that

$$\lim_{x\to a} 2x \ge \lim_{x\to a} \sqrt x$$

since strict inequalities does not necessarly hold in the limit.

In order to use the strict inequality, we need a stronger condition that is for example $2x\ge \sqrt x+1$ and then

$$\lim_{x\to a} 2x \ge \lim_{x\to a} \sqrt x+1 > \lim_{x\to a} \sqrt x$$

When we take the limit at infinity we have that both functions diverges at infinity and as a notation we can write

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} 2x = \lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt x =\infty$$

and with reference to the [extended real number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) we can write that

$$\lim_{x\to a} 2x \ge  \lim_{x\to a} \sqrt x$$

for $a\in[1,\infty] \subseteq \mathbb {\bar R}$.